# Do not render equations in rmarkdown documents when converting to plain markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Let's say I have the following rmarkdown document:

```
Inline equation: $x$

Display math: $$x$$
```

I render this with:

```
rmarkdown::render("test.rmd", clean=TRUE, output_format="md_document")
```

The resulting markdown file looks like this:

```
Inline equation: *x*

Display math:
*x*
```

I would like `render()` to not "touch" the equations. So, `$x$` should just say as `$x$` and `$$x$$` as `$$x$$` and should just be put into the markdown document as is. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's actually LaTeX code, we may use a backslash `\` (a single one) to escape the `$` to be evaluated as a special character. Thus, in an .Rmd document we may use:

```
Inline equation: \$x\$

Display math: \$\$x\$\$
```

### Yielding

[image]

Comment: That indeed works. But `\$x_i\$` turns into `$x\_i$`. Where does that extra slash come from and is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: @Wolfgang Hmm can't reproduce this, `\$x_i\$` works fine for me.

Comment: Strange. Turns into `$x\_i$` for me. But turns out this isn't a problem for the workflow I am trying to accomplish here (the markdown documents gets passed through pander one more time to another target format and then the slashes are filtered out).